# NSPasteboard: Getting the name of the application that initiated a drag and drop session

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nspasteboard

My Cocoa app can receive Drag operations from other applications.

Is there a way to determine which other application initiated the drag (i.e. from where the data is coming from)?

I've implemented `- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender`, but I could not find this kind of information in the dragging info object.

*Use case*: Users can select text in Safari and drop it into my app. I'd like to tell from which website the text was pasted.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is part of the API, so maybe if you explain your ultimate goal others will have alternative suggestions.